# Timeline movement lock turned off in Premiere Pro

Tags: adobe, premiere-pro

I have no idea how to word this correctly. Normally in Premiere Pro I can move clips on different layers and have them perfectly aligned from the beginning of the clip, but now that feature is gone for some reason. How can I turn it back on?

Answer (score 1):

Snapping - with the timeline panel highlighter, press <kbd>S</kbd> and look for the little magnet icon.

[image: snap]

https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/clips-sequence.html